# Can NHibernate query IN-Memory objects

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Like linq to objects, is it possible that nhibernate can query in memory objects? They have a very powerful API and it would be wonderful if it could query in memory objects.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but I know I've seen samples where NHibernate works with a SQLite database that is stored in memory. They often use it for building up a testing environment without requiring a test database.

Comment: Luke, take a look at Linq to NHibernate. It may be the closest to your request that I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it cant query your objects by default. Its ORM, not query query builder